# Environment Variables in Clarifai - clarifai_sample.js

Tags: token, clarifai

I put Client ID and Client Secret in environment variables `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` respectively. They are for the same application. I also generated a token. I am getting the following error message:

> TAG request encountered an unexpected error: {"status_code":
>   "TOKEN_APP_INVALID", "status_msg": "Application for this token is not
>   valid. Please  ensure that you are using ID and SECRET from same
>   application. "}

Can you please explain why?

Comment: Which language are you using? Are you using just the REST API, or one of the clients?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from the variables :)
(Been there done that)